# Loading a Keras model raises exception - Deploying a model with a TextVectorization layer

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I have trained a model with tensorflow 2.5.0 on **google colab** with the following structure:

```
encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(
  max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE,
  output_mode='int',
  output_sequence_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LEN
)

encoder.adapt(train_dataset.map(lambda text, label: text))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  encoder,
  tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(encoder.get_vocabulary()), 64, mask_zero=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,  return_sequences=True)),
  tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

when the training has successfully completed I saved the model like this

```
!mkdir -p saved_model

model.save('saved_model/my_model')
```

after downloading and loading the model with `tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')` on my local machine (different project without the code from colab) the function throws an exception that ends with:
`TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'vocabulary_size')`
How can I successfully run my model inside a python environment?

Comment: did you try saving as `.h5` file?

Comment: Yes however it raised another exception I can't remember

Comment: which versions are you using in both environments I mean Keras?

Comment: Google Colab uses tf 2.5.0 and my MacBook Pro M1 tf 2.4.1

Comment: You need to use the same version to load a model, it will not work with older versions.

Comment: Using the same version didn't work either, the issue was the TextVectorization layer. Loading a model with this layer requires the Tensorflow nightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to save the model as a .h5 file the following error occurred:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f4fa74fc37a7> in <module>()
----> 1 model.save('my_model.h5')

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in _legacy_weights(layer)
896         'Save or restore weights that is not an instance of `tf.Variable` is '
897         'not supported in h5, use `save_format=\'tf\'` instead. Got a model '
--> 898         'or layer {} with weights {}'.format(layer.__class__.__name__, weights))
899   return weights

NotImplementedError: Save or restore weights that is not an instance of `tf.Variable` is not supported in h5, use `save_format='tf'` instead.
Got a model or layer TextVectorization with weights 
[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_utils.TrackableWeightHandler object at 0x7f7415b59d10>]
```

Using the saved_model format and a production environment with the Tensorflow nightly v2.6.0.dev20210602 installed worked in the end